# Assuming that the graph of a function..Show that it is not continuous by finding an open set $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open.

Tags: general-topology

Assuming that the graph about is the graph of a function $f:  \mathbf R  \rightarrow \mathbf R$ Show that it is not continuous by finding an open set $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not open. [image]

I am not sure if the question is just asking for an example.  I am trying to come up with the correct set $V$... I obviously know that I need to include $2$... any suggestions would be beneficial.

Comment: Is your question about *this* graph, or given an arbitrary function which is not continuous etc.?

Comment: Just this graph

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

There is only one point of discontinuity, $2$ so this should be a glaring hint. What happens when you pick $V$ to be an open interval around $f(2)$ which is small enough not to meet the top part of the graph? What is $f^{-1}(V)$?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you may have an issue with how to pick $V$ and likely that you think $V$ has to exactly relate to the $y$ values of the function. This is an easy mistake to make and many students fall into this trap when first encountering the open set definition of continuity. The beauty of the definition of continuity is that you're allowed to pick $V$ *however you want* (as long as it is open). So.. let's pick $V = (0,2)$. The reason for this choice is that, as you noted, we need to somehow capture $x=2$ in the inverse image *and* we want to pick up the discontinuity. Then if we do $f^{-1}(V)$, what do we get?

[image]

Comment: See part of the problem is a literally get every question about the inverse image incorrect.  If you pick V = (0,2) then you are picking x values from (0, 2) correct?

Comment: No. You are picking **y** values between $0$ and $2$. $V$ lives in the codomain, not the domain. Give me a few minutes and I'll edit your graph to show you what I mean.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a drawing of what is going on. Is it clear to you now?